# asmx change DateTime format

Tags: json, web-services, datetime, asmx

Haven't found anything out there after doing some searches.

I'm wondering if

1. there's any way to specify how an `asmx WebService` serializes a `DateTime` to `json`?
2. Can this be setup as a webconfig setting? Or am I stuck with the `/Date(millis)/` format?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to do this, but one solution is to use a `double` value (or possibly `long` if you're not interested in fractional milliseconds) which contains the total number of milliseconds since the UnixEpoch.  You could use a helper class something like:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
   public static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    public static double ToUnixTime(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return (dateTime - UnixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Rather than having to store all dates as doubles in my classes, I decided to keep them as DateTime objects. Thus far, all the client serializers (gson, jquery) are able to add declare custom reviver/replacer functions to deal with the /Date()/ string. Just a note: .NET serializes using the /Date()/ format.. but isn't able to deserialize FROM that format, I found that strange.